# How to define a static private method outside the class in c++

Tags: class, struct, syntax-error, private-members

```
    #include <iostream>
    class BST {
    private:
        struct Bst_node
        {
            int data;
            struct Bst_node* left;
            struct Bst_node* right;
        }*root;

        // static Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr);
        static BST::Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr)
       {
       ptr = ptr->left;
        if (ptr == NULL) return NULL;
        while (ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->right;
        }
        return ptr;

    }

    public:
        void create()
        {
            root = new Bst_node;
            root->data = 8;
            root->right = NULL;
            root->left = new Bst_node;
            root->left->data = 10;
            root->left->left = NULL;
            root->left->right = NULL;
        }
        void print()
        {
            Bst_node * ptr = get_inorder_predecessor(this->root);
            if(ptr == NULL) std::cout<<"NULL\n";
            else std::cout<<ptr->data<<std::endl;
        }
    };  
    int main()
    {
    BST obj;
    obj.create();
    obj.print();
    return 0;
    }
```

The above code is working fine but when i define 'get_inorder_predecessor()' function outside the class it gives error see the below code.

```
#include <iostream>
class BST {
private:
struct Bst_node
    {
        int data;
        struct Bst_node* left;
        struct Bst_node* right;
    }*root;

    static Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr);
    

    public:
        void create()
        {`

            root = new Bst_node;
            root->data = 8;
            root->right = NULL;
            root->left = new Bst_node;
            root->left->data = 10;
            root->left->left = NULL;
            root->left->right = NULL;
        }
        void print()
        {
            Bst_node * ptr = get_inorder_predecessor(this->root);
            if(ptr == NULL) std::cout<<"NULL\n";
            else std::cout<<ptr->data<<std::endl;
        }
};  

static BST::Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr)
    {
        ptr = ptr->left;
        if (ptr == NULL) return NULL;
        while (ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->right;
        }
        return ptr;

    }
    
int main()
{
    BST obj;
    obj.create();
    obj.print();
    return 0;
}
```

See the ERRORS:

'''binary.cpp:33:13: error: 'struct BST::Bst_node' is private within this context
static BST::Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr)
^~~~~~~~
binary.cpp:4:12: note: declared private here
struct Bst_node
^~~~~~~~
binary.cpp:33:47: error: 'Bst_node' was not declared in this scope
static BST::Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr)
^~~~~~~~
binary.cpp:33:57: error: 'ptr' was not declared in this scope
static BST::Bst_node* get_inorder_predecessor(Bst_node* ptr)
^~~
'''

Comment: Please tell me reason why this is happening?

Comment: Remove the `static` from the definition. And you need to prefix the definition with the classname as well, so it becomes  `BST::Bst_node* BST::get_inorder_predecessor` - right now you are defining a new function, which is unrelated to the static member function